# How to get a LoL player's rank only with HTML/CSS, is it even possible ? Riot API is confusing me

Tags: html, api, riot-games-api

Novice html developer here, I was wondering how I could get my Lol Rank onto my site from Riot's API.

Is it possible to do it without Javascript ?

Comment: No..............

Comment: @Rob one could easily generate an SVG with the rank and embed it as an image.

Answer (score 0):

You'd need a proxy, server or "function", because you're not allowed to disclose your API key.

You could look at how to generate SVG badges, using an AWS Lambda for example. Then you'll just embed your rank as an image, and no JavaScript is required on the web page.

Answer (score -1):

No, it's not. You need the JS to do this.

If you can, use React and axios to get the response of the api. More about axios here: https://axios-http.com/ptbr/docs/intro